# Buildozer - Kivy failing to build : arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch'

Tags: android, python, kivy

Can someone help me please? I have been trying to build a very basic APK and I keep failing. My latest error is included below. Any help or tips/ideas is greatly appreciated.

OSX Maverick/ Python 2.7.7/ Cython 0.20.1

Many thanks in advance.

//Marc

###################

```
building 'pygame.imageext' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/src

arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /Users/holbrookm/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /Users/holbrookm/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-14/arch-arm -I/Users/holbrookm/Virtualenvs/kivywork/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/png -I/Users/holbrookm/Virtualenvs/kivywork/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/jpeg -I/Users/holbrookm/Virtualenvs/kivywork/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl/include -I/Users/holbrookm/Virtualenvs/kivywork/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_mixer -I/Users/holbrookm/Virtualenvs/kivywork/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_ttf -I/Users/holbrookm/Virtualenvs/kivywork/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/src/jni/sdl_image -arch x86_64 -D_REENTRANT -I/Users/holbrookm/Virtualenvs/kivywork/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c src/imageext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/src/imageext.o

arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory

arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch'

error: command 'arm-linux-androideabi-gcc' failed with exit status 1

# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d "marc_app"
```

Comment: check your bin folder there you will get your APK file.

Comment: I have checked the bin folder and unfortunately there is no apk file there. Has the apk file been compiled and completed? I understood the errors above mean that no file has been generated and that the process failed/

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: HI,I did but it took a re-install of the OS and my python libraries.